# How to out.print() HTML attributes in JSP?

Tags: java, html, jsp, attributes, tags

So the problem is that I'm wondering how i should `out.print()` attributes, i have seen people doing this:

```
<%
 out.println("<h1> Hello world </h1>");
%>
```

but how would i go about doing this:

```
<%
 out.println("<h1 align="center"> Hello world </h1>");
%>
```

Comment: Try it like this `out.println("<h1 align='center'> Hello world </h1>");` Nesting of double-quotes breaks your code.

Answer (score 2):

Double quotes in java are escaped inside the string value.

```
out.println("<h1 align=\"center\"> Hello world </h1>");
```

Answer (score 1):

what you should is always use double quotes as outer in your string and single quotes in inner string

ex

```
     out.println("<h1 align='center'> Hello world </h1>");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use string concatenation also like this,

```
 <% out.print("<h1 align='center'>"+"Hello World"+"</h1>"); %>
```